# How to give different toolbar settings to different tabs?

Tags: java, android, tabs, toolbar

I recently tried something different for my on development app but don't know how it works. I'm trying to add different actions (eg. Search)to each Tabs in more than one toolbar. I don't know how to explain my view well but the images below can make you understand what I'm trying to.
[image: toolbar settings]
In the Contacts tab there is a add user icon in toolbar and in the calls tab you can see add calls icon in toolbar and in the Chats tab you can see chats icon in toolbar. My question is how to give different ifRoom settings to different tabs like the above app. Hope it is well explained to get the right answer :)
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Do you know android's basics? Obviously you should make those option in menus as fragment's menu. Fragment used in tab...  It is all well explained in official basic guides

Comment: What for? It is all basics. Every fragment can have its own menu, which is shown when fragment is visible...

Comment: @Selvin don't be so rude ok! As if i have a done a crime to you.If you cannot help then please don't showoff as if you know everything!

Comment: You did not show any effort of resolve the problem by yourself. Also, seems like you do not know android's basics...   How should help looks in your opinion?  Full code? SO is not write the code for me service. Links? SO is not human search engine.

Comment: @Selvin : I got the answer my self bro! Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this code.

1. Add toolbar in your `Activity`, like you did.
2. Create menu for each fragment `res/menu/menu_one.xml` and ...
3. Add `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` in each fragment, like this:

.

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);// add menu which you created in step 2
       return true;
  }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // do stuff, like showing settings fragment
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); // important line
    }
```

4. And in `onCreate` add this like: `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

And it is it! :)